# Select average of column after using HOUR(date) for other column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

I have the following data in my MariaDB database:

[image]

I want to be able to to select average value of P2 for every hour. I have records every 5 minutes so you can assume that  the table looks the same for other hours.

Here is example fiddle:

https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=33ca7d9462a7b7af24a762072e621e7f&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb

I know it does not work now.
In example data we have:

```
('1', '2021-02-28 23:35:00', '100', '836327'),
  ('2', '2021-02-28 23:40:00', '200', '0'),
  ('3', '2021-02-28 23:45:00', '300', '0'),
  ('4', '2021-02-28 23:50:00', '400', '0'),
  ('5', '2021-02-28 23:55:00', '500', '0'),
```

So average P2 value for hour 23:00 should be 300.

Answer (score 2):

You need an average value for every hour, so you can use `AVG` function on `P2` column and then `GROUP BY HOUR(DT)`. Assuming you want to group for each date too, the resulting query will be look like this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(DT), HOUR(DT), AVG(P2)
FROM dobridol
GROUP BY DATE(DT), HOUR(DT)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query:

```
SELECT
    date_format(`dt`, '%Y-%m-%d') as `day`, 
    date_format(`dt`, '%H') as `hour`, 
    AVG(p2) AS hourly_average  
FROM dobridol
GROUP BY date_format(`dt`, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=d5fe8ee652673700599ab0995aebfa2f&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Result:

```
+============+======+================+
| day        | hour | hourly_average |
+============+======+================+
| 2021-02-28 | 23   | 300.0000       |
+------------+------+----------------+
| 2021-03-01 | 00   | 650.0000       |
+------------+------+----------------+
```